# Am I going beyond the scope of a get method when I test it with Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am testing a method with Mockito. The method itself is simple. It's a "get" method, named getPeriod(). But there are issues with it.

**Here is the story:**

My Java class has a method, named start(), which collects some configuration data from an external system and based on what is collected it sets some variables. One such variable is "period". If the method is unable to collect data from the external system (due to communication failure, and so on), it sets default values to those variables.

So, there are 2 situations

1. data were found externally
2. default data were used

But, do those situations matter when I test getPeriod()? Is the following not enough to test the method against some arbitrary constant JOB_PERIOD?

```
testgetPeriod {
   assertThat(comp.getPeriod(), equalTo(JOB_PERIOD));
}
```

**The problem is**, as far as setting the period is concerned, the control is with the start() method. So, do I consider those 2 scenarios ONLY while testing the start() method and let getPeriod() go with an easy, one-line, test like the above code?

Answer (score 1):

The reasons you list are not reasons to test getPeriod.

Instead, you need one or more unit tests that simulate external communication failure and verify that the Period value is correctly set to default data (it seems likely that these tests will include a call to getPeriod).

You also need one or more unit tests that simulate successful acquisition of period data and verify that the period value is correctly set (again, these tests are likely to include a call to getPeriod).

Comment: Thanks DwB. I see a dilemma here. Both getPeriod() and start() are test subjects. So, should I use getPeriod (which itself is a test subject) in order to aid in testing start()? But, then, there is no way to retrieve the private period variable without invoking getPeriod()!

Answer (score 0):

As per the Junit testing best practices  , your code is not correct ,
your test method indicates you are testing getPeriod method but there is no such method called on the class object , you are basically testing start method in your testcase

Comment: I have corrected the code I mentioned here. I wrongfully wrote comp.start(). I have changed that to comp.getPeriod().

Answer (score 0):

I'd say so. What I would do is mock out the period variable, and then in your testGetPeriod, assert that it gets the same object that you mocked out. That way, when you test start, you just need to make sure that it sets the period value correctly